# PhpStorm 6.0.1 - Shortcut to save activates search bar

Tags: editor, phpstorm

So i got the following problem. When I'm working inside the editor and press STRG + S (what should be save) the document gets saved, but what happens also is, that a search bar gets popped up and the next thing I write get's written into the search bar instead of the editor itself. I then have to click into the editor again to write there. This is pretty annoying since I save quite a lot. In the Keymapping STRG+S is set for Save all, so this doesn't make really sense for me.

As a comparison here two screenshots. The first one shows how it looks like, when I write something and didn't save yet. The second one shows what happens, as soon as I press STRG+S

[image: Screenshot One]
[image: Screenshot Two]

As you can see a search bar pops up and gets the focus of the cursor. This is what I'm trying to solve but can't find a solution for.

Comment: Try changing keymap to **default** one (or whatever is more logical to your OS -- `MacOS X 10.5+` for Mac)

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest version, 6.02, your problem should be solved.